# Situations where Entity Framework should NOT be used?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Are there any situations where EF is not a desirable solution for data access? I think back to the contrast between DataReader and DataSet and how the latter was often not desirable when trying to stream thru tons of data. So I'm curious if there are use cases where EF is not a good idea. Or perhaps alternately where EF presents challenges or gotchas with how its used? Thanks

Comment: Yes - bulk operations. If you want to insert ten of thousands of rows of new data (or export those), then EF is not your best choice. It works beautifully for handling single row/entities, or "manageable" lists thereof - but it's not made for bulk operations.

Comment: yup marc, I agree that's the obvious example for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking all abstrations do is present a facade to something. The reasons for the facade maybe for many reasons, though usually they present simplification over of a complexity.

The EF presents a ORM layering to reduce the impedance that comes from the complexity of mapping from a object oriented world to a relational world. In doing so it has a different overhead than in rolling your own mapping. In some ways it's easier and in other ways it's harder. Part of providing features is the increase in the overhead (be it in performance or effectiveness to the problem domain) and this needs to be managed. In addition an abstraction that simplyfies something (in my experience) usually introduces restrictions on what you can or cannot do. This also need to be considered in any design.

So the answer is - where the features provided by EF don't overcome the benefit and effort of being restricted by it's way of doing things.

A classic example if this is the simple CRUD client server appliation that can usually these days be auto generated using tools such as Codesmith or IronSpeed or simmilar.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. I wasn't asking for an overview of the architecture and description of what EF is. I was curious to hear of scenarios where it is a poor choice. Marc_s above makes a good point about bulk insert ETL type operations being ill-suited to EF. This is a rather obvious example of course but that's what I'm driving at, scenarios where EF is a poor choice

Comment: @snappymcsnap : I stand by what I said it's poor choice wherever it's not cost effective to use it over another technique. How you measure cost is down to you.

Comment: Fair enough, its a good point you make but I guess my reply to that is that its not specific to EF, you could apply that to any architectural decision or framework

Answer (score -7):

In about every non-trivial real-world situation, if you care more about user-satisfaction  then an empty promise of simplicity and programmer-convenience. and  if you care more about getting things done then debugging leaky abstractions.

Comment: What a wonderfully useful and informative answer.

Comment: What a great attempt at sarcasm